# how to control number of web service calls in jboss on windows

Tags: windows, web-services, jboss

i have jboss intalled on win 2008 r2 64bit machine. 
I want to control the number of web service requests processed on the jboss server. how to configure this?
more details:
OS - win 2008r2 server
JVM - 1.5, 32bit
jboss - 4.3.0

Comment: Number == concurrent requests?

Comment: yes, i want to control how many concurrent requests can be processed at any given point of time.